# How can I determine what the current stable version of Ruby is?

Tags: ruby

I want to write a Ruby method that does two things:

1. Determine what the current stable version of Ruby is. My first thought is to get the response from https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/ and use RegEx to isolate the phrase `The current stable version is [x]`. Is there is an API I'm not aware of?
2. Get the URL to download the .tar.gz of that release. For this I was thinking the same thing, get it from the output of the site URL.

I'm looking for advice about the best way to go about it, or direction if there's something in place I might use to determine my desired results.

Comment: You're right, BTW. There should be an API for this. The API could be as simple as a static `.txt` file at `http://ruby-lang.org/latestversion.txt` with an ASCII string `2.1.5-p274` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby code to fetch the download page, then parse the current version and the link URL:

```
html = Net::HTTP.get(URI("https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/"))
vers = html[/http.*ruby-(.*).tar.gz/,1]
link = html[/http.*ruby-.*.tar.gz/]
```

GitHub code: [ruby-stable-version.rb](https://github.com/SixArm/sixarm_unix_shell_scripts/blob/master/ruby-stable-version.rb)

Shell code:
[ruby-stable-version](https://github.com/SixArm/sixarm_unix_shell_scripts/blob/master/ruby-stable-version)

Comment: Simple and elegant with minimal dependence. Thank you! I just have to keep an eye out to make sure the first mention of the Ruby URL at the URL is the current stable and correct for my platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rbenv you can use ruby-build to get a list of ruby versions and then grep against that.

```
ruby-build --definitions | tail -r | grep -x -G -m 1 '[0-9]\.[0-9].[0-9]\-*[p0-9*]*'
```

You can then use that within your code like so:

```
version = `ruby-build --definitions | tail -r | grep -x -G -m 1 '[0-9]\.[0-9].[0-9]\-*[p0-9*]*'`.strip
```

You can then use this value to get the download URL.

```
url = "http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/#{version[0..2]}/ruby-#{version}.tar.gz"
```

And then download the file:

```
require 'open-uri'
open("ruby-#{version}.tar.gz", 'wb') do |file|
  file << open(url).read
end
```

Learn more about [rbenv here](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and [ruby-build here](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build).

Comment: Yeah, you can install it without rbenv using brew: `brew install ruby-build`

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to use the Ruby source repository. Check [`version.h`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_1/version.h#L1) in every branch, filter by `RUBY_PATCHLEVEL > -1` (`-1` is used for `-dev` versions), sort by `RUBY_VERSION` and take the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- Ruby's built-in [OpenURI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html), and [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), to read a page, parse it, search for certain tags, extract a parameter such as a "src" or "href".
- OpenURI to read the URL, or `curl` or `wget` at the command-line to retrieve the file.

Nokogiri's tutorials including showing how to use OpenURI to retrieve the page and hand it off to Nokogiri.

OpenURI's docs show how to "open" URLs and retrieve their content using `read`. Once you've done that, the data will be easy to save to disk using something like this for text files:

```
File.write('some_file', open('http://www.example.com/').read)
```

or for binary:

```
File.open('some_file', 'wb') { |fo| fo.write(open('http://www.example.com/').read) }
```

There are examples of using both Nokogiri and OpenURI for this all over Stack Overflow.